# How to change screen orientation from outside of activity?

Tags: android

I have searched a lot and found screen orientation can be changed from activity class by using the following code:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

But my requirement is to change the screen orientation from outside of an activity like from an **AsyncTask**. So please tell me if it is possible to do so or is there any alternate way of doing this.

Comment: declare interface inside AsyncTask and Implement it on Activity. Then call any functionality from AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible unless you pass the reference of `Activity`. This is bad in terms of design and you might end up scratching your head for potential memory leaks. I would recommend you not to do it outside of your Activity and if you do so remember to properly clean up the relative `Activity` references (you can use `WeakReference`).

Comment: ok thanks but say like I am launching an activity then can i pass change orientation thing in flag or something like that?

Comment: @sak `i pass change orientation thing in flag or something like that` what do you mean?